# Unable to install chromadb on Python 3 due to sub-dependency error

Tags: python, python-3.x, large-language-model, chromadb

I am trying to install the package for chromadb, but always receive the following message:

```
Collecting chromadb
  Using cached chromadb-0.4.24-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.3 kB)
Collecting build>=1.0.3 (from chromadb)
  Using cached build-1.1.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.2 kB)
Collecting requests>=2.28 (from chromadb)
  Using cached requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.6 kB)
Collecting pydantic>=1.9 (from chromadb)
  Using cached pydantic-2.6.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (85 kB)
Collecting chroma-hnswlib==0.7.3 (from chromadb)
  Using cached chroma-hnswlib-0.7.3.tar.gz (31 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000023CEE4B5A90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/setuptools/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000023CEF88A5D0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/setuptools/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000023CEF9AF6B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/setuptools/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000023CEF9E4620>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/setuptools/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000023CEF9E4A10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/setuptools/
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools>=42 (from versions: none)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools>=42
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

```
Comand --> pip install chromadb --proxy="<my proxy>"

python --version --> Python 3.12.2
pip --version --> 24.0
```

I also tried it with different Python versions from 3.10 to 3.12. but I always receive similar errors. It seems not to be a proxy error, because I am able to install other packages

Has anybody an idea on how to solve this issue ?

KR Philipp